# Is it possible to use ssr: true and ssr: false for different routes?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-content

I am using nuxt3 with route rules. I was wondering if it was possible to use the following route rules:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    components: true,
     routeRules: {
        '/**': { ssr: false},
        '/blogs/**': { ssr: true},
    },
    content: {
        experimental: {
            clientDb: true
        }
    },
    nitro: {
        prerender: {
            routes: ['/sitemap.xml', ...pageRoutes, ...contentRoutes]
        }
    },
    experimental: {
        payloadExtraction: true
    }

})
```

I am using nuxt/content as well. Each individual blog page is prerendered through `...contentRoutes`, and the `/blogs/**` pages show a collection of blogs to chose and filter from. Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. Nuxt content can't be found in production.